# How does (?<option>) differs from (?<option>:...) in Ruby regular expressions (Regex)?

Tags: ruby, regex

How does below mentioned differ from each other in Ruby regular expressions (Regex)?

- `(?imx)` and `(?-imx)`
- `(?imx:..)` and `(?-imx:..)`

How does `(?ix-ix: )` work in `Regex`? I found this documentation:

> - `(?imx)` Toggles i, m, or x options on.
> - `(?-imx)` Toggles i, m, or x options off.
> - `(?imx:..)` Toggles i, m, or x options on within parentheses.
> - `(?-imx:..)` Toggles i, m, or x options off within parentheses.
> - `(?ix-ix: )` Turns on (or off) i and x options within this noncapturing group.

But within the code how they will going to be used, couldn't understand. So any help with tiny codes to demonstrate the differences as mentioned above?

Comment: I think your post is somewhat unclear due to some grammar mistakes, but that's okay. Hopefully someone will help you by editing your question.

Comment: You can always ask on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you think that's unjustified :)

Comment: I suspect people feel your question is very easily solved by reading online documentation and trying some tests on your own. A really good way to see if you run a good chance of being downvoted is to search for one of the strings you have in bold in your question and see how many hits you get. If you get several in the first page returned on Google, then perhaps you should read all of those before asking here. That's a good rule-of-thumb mentioned often on the Meta site.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes,I hit on `Google` and got two of the search where only description has mentioned, not a single code i found to realize these frames. Thus asked helped from here.

Comment: I did a quick search for "(?imx) Toggles i, m, or x options on." and found six hits on the first page, not including the two for SO and a spin-off site. That's why you're getting downvoted.

Comment: @theTinMan you can see into them,none of them has detailed description with codes,and i also got those links. But not helped me at all :(

Comment: You'll need to work on improving your questions and spending more time exploring on your own then, because people will use that same test to explore YOUR question and will downvote or vote to close based on that simple test. While you might not agree with that, it's how people are and you're going to have a difficult time changing the public's ideas of what makes a good question.

Comment: Who down-vote me again? what the reason,come and tell me. This is not fare!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?x)` applies through the end of the *current* set of parentheses, or the entire regex if it's not inside parentheses.  `(?x:...)` applies to whatever's *inside* the parentheses.

So, really, this:

```
(?x: ... )
```

is just an easier way to write this:

```
(?:(?x) ... )
```

And it works like this:

```
/red (?i) blue ( ( (?x) ( (?-i) green ) yellow ) purple )/
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     'i' is turned on here...          and here
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          but 'i' is turned off here
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    'x' is turned on here
```

`(?s-m:...)` is another shortcut: it turns `s` *on*, and `m` *off*.  You could also write it as `(?:(?s)(?-m)...)`, but that's pretty hard to read.

`(?ix-ix:...)` is a pretty bad example, since it doesn't make any sense to turn `i` and `x` *both* on and off.

---

Examples:

This will match:

```
/one (?i)TWO THREE/.match 'one two three'
```

This will not, because the `i` flag only applies within the `()`:

```
/one ((?i)TWO) THREE/.match 'one two three'
```

This also won't, and is the same as the above, except that the parentheses *won't* capture:

```
/one (?i:TWO) THREE/.match 'one two three'
```

But these will match:

```
/one (?i:TWO THREE)/.match 'one two three'
/one (?i:TWO) three/.match 'one two three'
```

Comment: How are they differs as mentioned above? could you help me there also?

Comment: what else are you confused about?  `(?x)` works inside parentheses; `(?x:...)` is a shortcut for `(?:(?x)...)`.

Comment: ah, i see.  edited answer, but basically it just turns some flags on and other flags off at the same time.

Comment: `+1` to you! Thanks for the clarifications!